# SQL update query identifier too long

Tags: sql-update

This is my code.

I am trying to update a record on button click

```
 Dim conn2 As SqlConnection
            Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
            conn2 = New SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=false;User Id=justin;Data Source=ARULJUSTIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=firemaintain;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
            conn2.Open()
            cmd2.Connection = conn2
            'conn = "update hyrdranmaintain SET uhlcondition, uhdhcondition,uhrhcondition values @lcondition, @hcondition, @rhcondition Where Recordno = '" & txtcase.ToString & "'",conn
            cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE hydrantmaintain SET uhlcondition, uhdhcondition, uhrhcondition values @lcondition, @hcondition, @rhcondition Where Recordno= @rcordno"
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lcondition", cmblv.SelectedItem)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hcondition", cmbdh.SelectedItem)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rhcondition", cmbrh.SelectedItem)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rcordno", Trim(txtcase.ToString))
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

and I am getting a error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled Message=Incorrect syntax near ','
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct syntax for an update. It should be something like:

```
UPDATE hydrantmaintain 
   SET uhlcondition  = @lcondition
      ,uhdhcondition = @hcondition
      ,uhrhcondition = @rhcondition 
WHERE Recordno= @rcordno
```